# Issue Creating a Table based on Macro's Parameter Name

Tags: sas

So I will briefly explain my code structure before I dive into the issue.

1. I've a macro

   ```
   %Sales (Outdata= , dt =, Outdata2= , Outdata3= );
   (
     I create a table &outdata by (Select * from XYZ);
     Proc SQL;
     Create table &Outdata._1 as 
     (  
     )
   %mend Sales
   ```
2. Now I call the macro

   ```
   %Sales (Outdata = sales_final_Oct17, dt='2017-10-01');

   Libname ABCDEFG
   ```
3. I Create a data set

   ```
    Data ABCDEFG.all_sales_test;
    Set  ABCDEFG. all_Sales
    sales_final_Oct17_1;
    incur_month = month(rept_dt);
    run;
   ```

   Above (1 to 3) is the original code flow and it works fine.

   My Problem:

   I'm using a dynamic way of generating file name for each month (so that each month I do not manually enter file_name_month and date.
4. File name code

   ```
   %let Last_Month = intnx('month', current_date,-1, "beginning");
   Name = 'Sales_final';
   Last_Month_Name = name|| put(&last_month, monyy7.);
   Call SYMPUTX('Last_Month_Name_v', Last_Month_Name);
   run;
   ```

Call Macro

```
    %Sales(outdata=&Last_Month_Name, dt = 'Dynamic date');
```

Till this point everything works fine. The moment I create a data set similar to step 3 (above), the code breaks.

```
    Libname ABCDEFG

    Data ABCDEFG.all_sales_test;
    Set  ABCDEFG.all_Sales
    Last_Month_Name_1;
    incur_month = month(rept_dt);
    run;
> Error Message: File ABCDEFG.LAST_MONTH_NAME_1.DATA does not exist.
```

What should I do to get rid of this error? It seems, if I pass a static name in the macro and then use the same name with "_1" it works fine but when I pass dynamic reference, then the data Set step fails with the above error message.

Any help is much appreciated. I'm new to SAS so excuse me if it's a silly question. Thanks.

Comment: What is the value of `Last_Month_Name` macro variable? Running `%put &Last_Month_Name.;` will print the value to log. I see you creating  only variable `Last_Month_Name_v`.

Comment: For future reference, your question contains quite a lot of information that isn't required.  To get a faster/better response on stack overflow it is recommended to provide a simple example that others can run, and contains the minimum amount of information necessary to demonstrate or recreate the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In (1) the macro code is using the value of the macro parameter (or local macro variable) `OUTDATA` to create a dataset. In (2) you are supplying a value for `OUTDATA` in your call and in (3) you are using the same value again in the `set` statement.

One way to not have to type the value twice is to store the value into a macro variable then just reference that macro variable's value in steps (2) and (3).

So in (4) you did create a macro variable,`Last_Month_Name_v` , but you then used the value of a different macro variable, `&Last_Month_Name` in the macro call. But instead of using the macro variable in the `set` statement you just referenced some other dataset,`Last_Month_Name_1` , that you never mentioned before at all.

Here are the simplified key steps in the process you want for how to create and use the macro variable. I have put in `...` to show where I have left out parts of a statement or statements so we can concentrate on the flow of the macro variable and its value.

First you set the macro variable to some name that you want to use. Let's just use `anything` as the name for this example.

```
%let last_month_name= anything;
```

Then you use the value in the macro call to create the dataset. Notice the `&` before the name, that is what tells the macro processor to replace the name with the value.  The period after the name tells the macro processor that is the end of the macro variable name.

```
%sales(outdata=&last_month_name.  .... )
```

Then you can use the value again later when you want to tell the `set` statement which dataset to read.

```
set .... &last_month_name. ;
```

Now your posted macro `%sales` does not actually create the dataset named `anything`. Instead it appears to create a dataset named `anything_1`.  Personally I don't know why that is there, but if you keep it that way then you need add the `_1` back to the end of the macro variable's value in the `set` statement. Just do it in the same way that you did in the macro's code.

```
set .... &last_month_name._1 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Working with macros is one of the harder parts of SAS and can be very confusing to newcomers.  Below is a simplified working example that demonstrates the approach I would take.

First we dynamically calculate the name of the table we want to save the results to:

```
%let current_date = %sysfunc(date());
%let last_month = Sales_final_%sysfunc(intnx(month, &current_date, -1, beginning), monyy7.);
%put &=last_month;
```

The output from the `put` statement in the above step is:

```
LAST_MONTH=Sales_final_OCT2017
```

Note that in the above code, I'm passing two parameters to `%sysfunc()`.  The first parameter is the call to the `intnx()` function.  The second parameter (`monyy7.`) is what format to apply to the result being returned from the function call.

Also note that there is no need to concatenate the prefix (`Sales_final_`) to the `%sysfunc()` result because when working with the macro language, the result of `%sysfunc()` is subsituted in place.  There is no concatenation operator in the macro language at all - everything is based off of macro substitution.

Then it's a simple case of passing that value into the macro as shown below:

```
%macro sales(outdata=);
  proc sql;
    create table &outdata._1 as select * from sashelp.class;
  quit;
%mend;

%sales(outdata=&last_month);
```

You should be able to modify the above into what you need.

Comment: Thanks a lot Robert! Appreciate it!!